# Update state during animation in react native?

Tags: animation, react-native

I have several active animations in a component. When I am trying to update a component state during these animations they stop due to the rerendering process. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

I am using an Animation similar to the example in the [react native documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animations.html) but with a longer duration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shouldComponentUpdate. With this you can define wether the component should rerender.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate

Comment: It misses some details but it should be the answer. RN does not seem to take animation in account during reconciliation phase. So if you trigger a component update during the animation, your animation will step to the end value without transition.

Answer (score 0):

I know that its a little late for answering but just in case you or someone else still needs it. You can consider using `useNativeDriver: true`. You can check the explanation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated). I basically lets you bypass that kind of blocking actions caused by callbacks in most cases.