# Updating state during animation stops animation from functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm attempting to use a draggable component that when dragged also creates a progress bar like effect. It's almost working but I have something weird going on.

In my `onDrag` handler I update the state of the bar so that the bar can render its appropriate width. But as soon as I set the state, my animation resets because the internal `panResponder` re-creates itself.

I'm new to react (and react-native). There are several similar problems but i can't work out what they are *doing* to resolve the problem.

[React Native state update during animation "resets" the animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780053/react-native-state-update-during-animation-resets-the-animation)

[Update state during animation in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723338/update-state-during-animation-in-react-native)

Here is a snack of the component I'm trying to produce.

https://snack.expo.io/mHaw0gLLz

Comment: I was looking at your code and saw that the Draggable was not moving, try setting  x={barWidth ? barWidth: padding} to the draggable component.

Comment: I update my answer with a good expo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the state he renders everything again and gives you the position of X again according to the figure you gave him

You can use the Animated component to change the drag width without changing the state

Attaches you an example

Successfully :)

add import

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';
```

add ref animated value

```
const widthAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
```

change animated value

```
const onDrag=(event, gestureState)=> {
  let width = Math.min(Math.max(gestureState.moveX, iconSize), dragWidth);
  Animated.timing(widthAnim, {
    toValue: Math.max(width - padding, 0),
    duration: 1,
  }).start();
}
```

Now use it in bar component!

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.bar, { width: widthAnim }]} />
```

[fix expo](https://snack.expo.io/@yoel301/animation-issue)